# ogrinfo sql example

Tags: gdal, ogr

I'm having trouble learning how to query my shapefiles for certain features.  I have a shapefile that looks something like this when I summarize it using the following command:

```
ogrinfo -al -geom=OFF tl_2013_us_uac10.shp

OGRFeature(tl_2013_us_uac10):3599
  UACE10 (String) = 31450
  GEOID10 (String) = 31450
  NAME10 (String) = Franklin--Highland Lake, NJ
  NAMELSAD10 (String) = Franklin--Highland Lake, NJ Urban Cluster
  LSAD10 (String) = 76
  MTFCC10 (String) = G3500
  UATYP10 (String) = C
  FUNCSTAT10 (String) = S
  ALAND10 (Real) = 84345960
  AWATER10 (Real) = 3320730
  INTPTLAT10 (String) = +41.1696387
  INTPTLON10 (String) = -074.5456645

OGRFeature(tl_2013_us_uac10):3600
  UACE10 (String) = 16171
  GEOID10 (String) = 16171
  NAME10 (String) = Chester, NY
  NAMELSAD10 (String) = Chester, NY Urban Cluster
  LSAD10 (String) = 76
  MTFCC10 (String) = G3500
  UATYP10 (String) = C
  FUNCSTAT10 (String) = S
  ALAND10 (Real) = 9360429
  AWATER10 (Real) = 3420
  INTPTLAT10 (String) = +41.3627073
  INTPTLON10 (String) = -074.2780785
```

How can I query for features that have NJ in their Name10 field, for example?  I tried something like this:

```
ogrinfo -al -sql "SELECT * FROM 'tl_2013_us_uac10' WHERE UACE10 = 16171" tl_2013_us_uac10.shp
```

but I get this error:

```
INFO: Open of `tl_2013_us_uac10.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
ERROR 1: Type mismatch or improper type of arguments to = operator.
```

Can anyone help me out or point me to a good resource?

Comment: Field UACE10 is listed as string. You're querying with an int.

Comment: A good resource is https://github.com/dwtkns/gdal-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are the features that contain the `NJ` string in their `Name10` field:

```
ogrinfo -al -where "NAME10 LIKE '%NY'" tl_2013_us_uac10.shp
```

where the percent symbol (`%`) matches any number of characters.

Instead, your example query should be:

```
ogrinfo -al -sql "SELECT * FROM tl_2013_us_uac10 WHERE UACE10 = '16171'" tl_2013_us_uac10.shp
```

or, more simply:

```
ogrinfo -al -where "UACE10 = '16171'" tl_2013_us_uac10.shp
```

The better resource I know about OGR SQL is its official [documentation page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html). Another useful resource for more advanced purpose is the [SQLite SQL dialect](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html) that extends the OGR SQL including the Spatialite SQL functions among other things.

Comment: Antonio, I am trying to do something similar to this but using a GPKG data source:

```ogrinfo -al -sql "SELECT * FROM tl_2013_us_uac10 WHERE UACE10 = '16171'" tl_2013_us_uac10.shp```
However I keep running into a "no such table" error. Any suggestions for sqlite syntax to recognize the table? I have a data source "cutblocks" with a single layer "layer1" ; but this sql statement fails:

```SELECT * FROM cutblocks layer1 WHERE BLOCK_STATUS_DATE = '2019/12/03'```